# SettingsPropertyValue.SerializedValue is null, unless I view the variable through locals

Tags: c#, serialization, application-settings

I'm storing some common settings used in a C# program inside the `ApplicationSettings`. Most of the settings are strings, but one of them is a `StringCollection`.

A null exception is occurring in some code that loops through the default settings at `Properties.Settings.Default` and adds them to a dictionary (in preparation to send as parameters), as shown below.

```
// Generate parameters
Dictionary<string, string> signalparams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Add parameters
foreach (SettingsProperty property in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    SettingsPropertyValue value = new SettingsPropertyValue(property);

    if (value.Property.SerializeAs == SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)
    {
        // Here's where the error occurs
        signalparams.Add(value.Name, value.SerializedValue.ToString());
    }
    else if (value.Property.SerializeAs == SettingsSerializeAs.String)
    {
        signalparams.Add(value.Name, value.PropertyValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

The strings settings are added fine, but when it reaches the `StringCollection`, it (correctly) evaluates that the property has `SerializeAs == SettingsSerializeAs.Xml`. However, the `SerializedValue` is null, and thus `ToString()` throws an exception.

The strange thing is that when running the debugger, the `SerializedValue` is null *until* I try viewing the `value` variable's properties in the locals windows. At that point, `SerializedValue` contains the correct XML serialized format for the `StringCollection`, and the program continues fine.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stems probably from the fact that `SerializedValue` is a property that is implemented something like that:

```
public object SerializedValue
{
  get
  {
    if (this._ChangedSinceLastSerialized)
       return CalculateSerializedData();
    else
       return _cachedData;
   }
}
```

What happens in your case, in my opinion, is that you're getting _cachedData when you first access the SettingPropertyValue, then, by viewing `value` via the debugger, you cause `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` to be `true` which causes the next call to `SerializedValue` property to return the actual serialized value.

The next question is to find out why `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` in your case is set to `false`.  The logic of `SettingsPropertyValue` says (you can see it in Reflector in `PropertyValue` property of the class) that `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` is set to true when the user either accesses the settings (in case of most object types), so for example merely accessing your setting like that: MyAppSettings.Default.MySettingObject would change `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` to `true`.

What could happen in your case that you have code similar to this:

```
object storingObject = MyAppSettings.Default.MySettingObject;
// Now I will use storingObject to access the setting.
```

Once you do something like that and keep using `storingObject` instead of directly accessing `MyAppSettings` you can create a situation in which the object changed while `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` remains `false`.

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. As far as it goes, I'm not retrieving an object from the settings like you showed, I'm simply trying to retrieve the serialized value with no previous modification to the setting. It may be that `_ChangedSinceLastSerialized` defaults to `false`, even if the object is never serialized. Nonetheless, I did work around the issue by serializing the object manually.

Answer (score 0):

I actually dropped trying to use `SettingsPropertyValue` and decided to serialize the object to XML manually. I simply used the `SettingsProperty.Name` as a key to retrieve the values of the settings stored in `Properties.Settings.Default`, since it is a dictionary-like object. It fixed the issue, but of course the root cause still remains unknown. The revised code looks something like this:

```
// Generate parameters
Dictionary<string, string> signalparams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Add parameters
foreach (SettingsProperty property in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    if (property.SerializeAs == SettingsSerializeAs.String)
    {
        signalparams.Add(property.Name, Properties.Settings.Default[property.Name].ToString());
    }
    else if (property.SerializeAs == SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)
    {
        // Serialize collection into XML manually
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(Properties.Settings.Default[property.Name].GetType());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, Properties.Settings.Default[property.Name]);
        writer.Close();

        signalparams.Add(property.Name, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```